# guzzlehttp Request Error 502 with Nginx Setting

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5.4, guzzle

## My nginx configures

file nginx/nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        root   /Users/My/Documents/web;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include        fastcgi.conf;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }

    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
    include servers/*;
}
```

file nginx/servers/myhost.conf

```
# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
server {
    # SSL configuration

    # Enable Nginx HTTP/2.0 Protocol
    listen       8081 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:8081 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;
    root    /Users/My/Documents/web/star/public;
    index   index.php;

    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/json;
    gzip_comp_level  9;

    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
    }
    error_log   /Users/My/Documents/web/star/storage/logs/error.log;
    access_log  /Users/My/Documents/web/star/storage/logs/access-$year-$month-$day.log  main;

    # SSL certificate configuration
    ssl_certificate /Users/My/Documents/ssl/certs/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /Users/My/Documents/ssl/private/nginx.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_dhparam  /Users/My/Documents/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 180m;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;
    #includeSubDomains" always;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors  on;

        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

## My Code

I use following code to requests any website but also show error

```
$client = new GuzzleClient([
    'timeout'  => 5.0,
    'cookies' => true,
    'headers' => [
        'User-Agent' => static::USER_AGENT
    ],
]);

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://google.com');
dd($crawler);
```

## My Error

nginx error.log

> 2017/08/27 19:33:45 [error] 27427#0: *54 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1:8081"

Comment: Put just an echo in your php page and see if it works

Comment: it works if I add phpinfo in route/web.php

Answer (score 1):

I use Mac - High Series, I just fallback to php 7.0 then work.... it's not related to nginx. Possible some package crush php-upstream

Comment: one more test. I use Docker with php 7.1 is work. Maybe Mac version problem